# Is there a Counterparty Whitepaper?

Tags: counterparty

Is there a Counterparty whitepaper? What about a specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a counterparty whitepaper: https://github.com/CounterpartyXCP/Counterparty

Comment: This link is no longer valid, please verify the link.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

The link you provided seems dead by now but there is an online documentation available at http://counterparty.io/docs/about_counterparty/.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://github.com/CounterpartyXCP/Documentation/ and search the repo for "protocol specification" (or API or whatever).
The current link for the protocol specification is https://github.com/CounterpartyXCP/Documentation/blob/master/Developers/protocol_specification.md